# Adding spring AOP(Aspect Oriented Programing) logs

Tags: spring, log4j, aop

I have used spring aop (aspect oriented programing) in my web application. Now I want to add logs to the places where Join-points occur. How can I configure my log4j xml for this task.

Answer (score 3):

For this requirement i have created one Aspect logger. this works on different layers like controller, service DAO with different level of logging.

```
@Aspect
public class LoggerAspect {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(LoggerAspect.class);

    @Autowired
    private RequestInfo requestInfo;

    @Around("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
    public Object logWebRequest(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        Object obj;
        Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null) {
            Object user = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                    .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            LOGGER.info("User: " + user);
        }
        LOGGER.info("Controller UUID: " + requestInfo.getRequestUUID());
        LOGGER.info("Controller URL: " + requestInfo.getRequestMethod());
        LOGGER.info("Controller Method: " + pjp.getSignature());
        logArguments(pjp);
        try {
            obj = pjp.proceed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Controller:" + e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
        if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOGGER.debug("Returns: " + obj);
            LOGGER.debug("Controller Response Time: "
                    + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " ms");
        }
        return obj;
    }

    @Around("execution(public * com.common.service..*.*(..))")
    public Object logCommonServiceRequest(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp)
            throws Throwable {
        return logServiceRequest(pjp);
    }

    @Around("execution(public * com.modules.*.service..*.*(..))")
    public Object logModulesServiceRequest(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp)
            throws Throwable {
        return logServiceRequest(pjp);
    }

    private Object logServiceRequest(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable,
            Exception {
        Object obj;
        if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOGGER.debug("Service: " + pjp.getTarget().getClass() + " -- "
                    + pjp.getSignature());
            logArguments(pjp);
        }
        try {
            obj = pjp.proceed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Service Exception:" + e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
        if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled())
            LOGGER.debug("Service Returns: " + obj);
        return obj;
    }

    @Around("execution(public * com.common.dao..*.*(..))")
    public Object logCommonDAORequest(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        return logDAORequest(pjp);
    }

    @Around("execution(public * com.modules.*.dao..*.*(..))")
    public Object logModulesDAORequest(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp)
            throws Throwable {
        return logDAORequest(pjp);
    }

    private Object logDAORequest(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable,
            Exception {
        Object obj;
        if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOGGER.debug("DAO: " + pjp.getTarget().getClass() + " -- "
                    + pjp.getSignature());
            logArguments(pjp);
        }
        try {
            obj = pjp.proceed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("DAO Exception:" + e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
        if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled())
            LOGGER.debug("DAO Returns: " + obj);
        return obj;
    }

    private void logArguments(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
        StringBuffer argLog = new StringBuffer();
        for (Object arg : pjp.getArgs()) {
            argLog.append(arg);
            argLog.append(",");
        }
        LOGGER.info("Args: " + argLog);
    }

}


<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true">
    <aop:include name="loggerAspect" />
</aop:aspectj-autoproxy>

<bean id="loggerAspect" class="com.service.LoggerAspect">
</bean>
```

Comment: What you have mention here is another aspect called LoggingAspect, what I want is to find how it is called by the spring framework whent the join points are met. For that purpose I need find out a way to add logs for org.springframework.aop with a logging level. Thats what my problem is about.